# Global dictionary vs queue and distributor for thread safety

Tags: python, multithreading, ipc

I have a dictionary with a few million entries.  Every couple of seconds, each of these few million entries are updated.  There are several threads that read (and only read) the dictionary.

I am abstracting everything away (from the point of view of the dict consumer), so it will look the same in the end - but I am worried about the performance of using a global dictionary (with a lock) vs. a queue (consumers request an entry from the dict controller, get an answer, and go along their way).

I like the queue/controller idea because it seems cleaner.  No global lock / dict, everything's synchronized.  I don't like it because in my experience, queues are slow.  I've also considered using zmq IPC as a replacement, but don't have any experience with that mechanism.

Which method of synchronization, lock or queue/zmq, will be more safe and efficient?

Comment: How is the dictionary updated ?  why do you need synchronization if they only read from it ?

Comment: @EvyatarMeged - I have one thread that reads from hardware and updates the dictionary every couple of seconds, and multiple threads that do different things with the values in the dictionary.  One writer, multiple readers.  Maybe I understand the dicts wrong but I am looking at synchronization because I fear a scenario of a race condition where the write worker is in the middle of writing what a read worker is currently reading.

Comment: Understood. I missed that thread that writes to the dictionary.

Comment: as cpython threads cannot run in parallel, I don't see queue has any advantage over dict with a lock.